# Как объединить объекты одного массива по одинаковому значению объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеем массив с объектами:

```
[{
    "id": 326277,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231.5"
  },
  {
    "id": 326278,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231"
  },
  {
    "id": 326279,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231"
  },
  {
    "id": 326280,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "230"
  }
]
```

Как видно есть одинаковые значения "coll" = 231, как преобразовать массив, что бы в результате объединить объекты с одинаковыми значениями "coll" в один массив как в примере ниже:

```
[
  [{
    "id": 326277,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231.5"
  }],
  [{
      "id": 326278,
      "part": 2,
      "coll": "231"
    },
    {
      "id": 326279,
      "part": 2,
      "coll": "231"
    }
  ],
  [{
    "id": 326280,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "230"
  }]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала группируем по полю "coll", а далее возвращаем только значения

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 326277,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231.5"
  },
  {
    "id": 326278,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231"
  },
  {
    "id": 326279,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "231"
  },
  {
    "id": 326280,
    "part": 2,
    "coll": "230"
  }
];

let res = Object.values(
  data.reduce((r, cur) => {
    const key = 'k' + cur['coll']; // символ "k" добавлен, чтобы автоматически не сортировало по цифровым ключам 
    (r[key] = r[key] || []).push(cur);

    return r;
  }, {})
);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо, без вас бы наверное еще на неделю отложил этот вопрос. Думал, что надо использовать reduce, но сам бы до конца бы не разобрался. У меня всегда возникают проблемы, когда необходимо преобразование массивов/объектов, можете посоветовать что ни будь?